# NAS IP is outside DHCP Range - now cannot access it

Tags: networking, router, nas, dhcp, synology

I have a NAS-DS216j and it is not showing up on my DHCP list. As a result, I don't know what it's IP address is and cannot connect to it in a browser, or the Synology Web Assistant (http://find.synology.com/ or synology-assistant-6.2-23733.dmg).

My TP-LINK C2 AC750 Routers DHCP range is 192.168.0.100 - 192.168.0.199. So I am guessing the reason is because the NAS-DS216j's IP address is outside this range.

I have a MacBook, and when I go to Finder, I can see the NAS-DS216j. I can browse the folders, so this means it is up and running.

Does anyone know how I can access the NAS-DS216j? I think my best solution would be to change the NAS-DS216j's IP address to something in the DHCP range (e.g. 192.168.0.105). But this doesn't really make sense, because the DHCP should be allocating an address to the NAS-DS216j.

Any advise welcome please.

UPDATE

I just discovered (by using DS Finder) that the NAS-DS216j's IP address is 192.168.8.104, which is outside the DHCP range. How do I change the NAS-DS216j's IP address to be inside the range?

p.s. My MacBook doesn't have an ethernet port to connect to the NAS (I do have a USB adapter though, will try connect via USB).

More info

My DHCP Client list is:

```
ID  Client Name MAC Address Assigned IP Lease Time
1   Unknown 00:04:4B:84:73:7F   192.168.0.103   01:20:43
2   LGwebOSTV   38:8C:50:17:0F:17   192.168.0.101   00:55:53
3   Samsung-Galaxy-S7-ed
ge  AC:5F:3E:EB:33:3F   192.168.0.102   Permanent
4   Galaxy-A5-2017  58:C5:CB:C5:12:E3   192.168.0.104   Permanent
5   Richards-MBP    F4:0F:24:34:77:F1   192.168.0.105   Permanent
6   Google-Home A4:77:33:3F:CC:C0   192.168.0.108   Permanent
7   Unknown F8:46:1C:00:EA:F2   192.168.0.109   Permanent
```

Comment: It is not the DHCP range that's important, but the subnet range, which I am guessing is 192.168.0.0 to 192.168.0.255. In fact, if you set the address manually, you should assign an address within the subnet, but outside the DHCP range, eg 192.168.0.99. I have a different TP-Link router (W9980), whose firmware has an address reservation section to make the router return a specific fixed address in response to a DHCP request. I use this for my NAS drives, so that all clients know how to access them, but to use it you'll need to set the NAS to use DHCP.

Comment: Hi AFH, thank you for the feedback.  My issue is I cannot access the NAS (apart from seeing it in Finder). So I am not sure how to change it to use DHCP. Any ideas?

Comment: If you are sure a factory reset won't erase data, this should set the network interface to DHCP (maybe try with the disc removed). Otherwise, try setting a route or changing your subnet mask to 255.255.240.0 in the router, which should give access to all of 192.168.0.0 to 192.168.15.255. You may need to reboot or change the routing table to establish the correct route entry. In my Linux version of `route`, this would be `Destination 192.168.0.0 Gateway * Genmask 255.255.240.0 Flags U ...` on the normal interface. Once the NAS has a 192.168.0.* address, you can restore the 255.255.255.0 mask.

Answer (score 0):

To discover network devices(IP, open ports...) on a network, you can use [fing](https://www.fing.io/) utility that runs on most popular platforms, phones and computers.

If you'd like your NAS to get new IP address dynamically at each start, you need to change  NAS's network settings from manual IP assignment to [DHCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol)

Connect via browser to IP address you discovered for your NAS and set DHCP (Get network configuration automatically) in `Control panel->Network->Network Interfaces-LAN(connected)`

Comment: I am not sure how to connect to my NAS on 192.168.8.104. The browser times out if I try, or if I try ping it. I have now bought an adapter to connect my MacBook to the ethernet port on the NAS, but still can't access it.

Comment: Try http://192.168.8.104:5000, http://192.168.8.104:5001, http://192.168.8.104:5002

Comment: Nope.  I tried each of there with the NAS plugged into the MacBook and the NAS plugged into the router. It just times out eventually.

Comment: Use program `fing` to scan IP 192.168.8.104 do discovery open ports

Answer (score 0):

Putting something like a NAP into the DEEP range with a fixed up address is asking for trouble, as the router could assign the address to another device if the NAP is powered down. This would make a nasty up conflict with you completely unable to access the device until the conflicting device is dropped from the network.
As someone said earlier, keep the device outside the DHCP range, and make sure that you have assigned the correct subnet and gateway addresses for your network. 
Usually the subnet for ipv4 will be 
255.255.255.0 
And the gateway address will be the same as the router up address. 
Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Eric. My settings are: IP Address:192.168.0.1 and Subnet Mask:255.255.255.0. But I do not know how to access the  NAS.  I have bought a cable to connect my MacBook directly to the ethernet port on the NAS, but still cannot see it.

Answer (score 0):

use paperclip to reset the nas, set new ip address for nas to 192.168.0.200,

for ip netmask/gateway see values on your pc (windows ipconfig, linux ifconfig)

https://www.synology.com/en-global/knowledgebase/DSM/tutorial/General/How_to_reset_my_Synology_NAS